# how to make hover effect on pattern?

Tags: svg

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <style> 
 svg{
  overflow:hidden;
 }
  defs:hover{
    transform:scale(1.2);
  }
 </style>
<body style="background:url(http://namonitore.ru/uploads/catalog/znamenitosti/karolina_kurkova__i_devushki_v_bikini_1280.jpg); background-size:cover;">



<svg width="400" height="240">
  <polygon points="10 220, 10 10, 280 10,380 220"
  style="fill:green; stroke:green; stroke-width:3; opacity="1" />

</svg>



<svg width="400" height="240" style="position:relative; left:-120px;">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="400" height="240">
            <image xlink:href="http://www.imagefully.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Sexy-Pause-Girl-Pic.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="240"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
  <polygon points="110 220,10 10,380 10,380 220"
  style="fill:url(#img1); stroke:0; stroke-width:0; opacity="1" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

It is necessary that when you hover over the girls , the effect was as if with background-position.
I do not know much English , but ask longer who.
how to make the zoom effect when you hover over the image of girls ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly then you should add a class to the polygon that's next to the `<defs>` element, add a class and use css on that polygon. For
example:

```
<svg width="400" height="240" style="position:relative; left:-120px;">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="400" height="240">
            <image xlink:href="http://www.imagefully.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Sexy-Pause-Girl-Pic.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="240"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
  <polygon class="girls" points="110 220,10 10,380 10,380 220"
  style="fill:url(#img1); stroke:0; stroke-width:0; opacity="1" />
</svg>
```

And then in your CSS instead of:

```
defs:hover{
    transform:scale(1.2);
  }
```

Do this:

```
polygon.grils:hover{
    transform:scale(1.2);
  }
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/meoLe830/#&togetherjs=44p7vNetfn here is a link to the sandbox , see for yourself - the effect is zero

Comment: You dud nothing what I wrote in the answer

Comment: Daniel sorry , turned out